# How would I host the static HTML, CSS, and JS files to host Swagger UI without using Node?

Tags: api, swagger

I want to host the Swagger UI behind the same webserver our API is running on (at least on dev and staging). Is it possible to do that without having to use Node whatsoever? I feel that it should be possible to host the static HTML, CSS and JS files but I can't see how.

This page* on Github suggests that `swagger-ui-dist` is designed for this scenario but the related page** doesn't really explain how to implement it but seems to show that Node is still required anyway.

I find the docs quite confusing.

*https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui

**https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-dist

Answer (score 0):

I just worked it out. All the static files I require are in the `dist` directory.